# Is there a better way to do a find with optional insert using unordered_map of objects with no default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class CEvent
{
public:
    CEvent(std::string const&) {}
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, CEvent> m_messageList;

CEvent& GetMessageEvent(std::string const& name)
{
   auto it = m_messageList.find(name);
   if (it == m_messageList.end())
   {
      auto pair = m_messageList.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
         std::forward_as_tuple(name),  // Copy-construct 'name' as the key
         std::forward_as_tuple(name)); // Construct CEvent in-place with the name

      return pair.first->second;
   }

   return it->second;
}
```

([Live Sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b8ec6026de6ffaf))

I think the code is pretty clean, but I don't like that I have to do a `find` separate from `emplace`. Is there a way to do this better? Or is this "good enough"? I know I could probably call `emplace` instead of `find` first, to accomplish both tasks, but this means creating a `CEvent` every time, even if no real insert happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once C++17 is released (or if your compiler supports prerelease versions),

`return m_messageList.try_emplace(name, name).first;` should do the trick.

Comment: Will that work if `CEvent`'s constructor is marked `explicit`? i.e. would `piecewise_construct` be needed?

Comment: The `piecewise_construct` behaviour is included. See e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace.